# Download error on (…) hostname <proxy> doesn't match either of '*.c.ssl.fastly.net', (…) when running buildout behind proxy

Tags: python, ssl, buildout

I'm trying to build a project which uses Buildout and I'm behind a proxy but there's a problem with hostname verification. I couldn't find the root of the problem as passing multiple `-v` options to `buildout` command seems to not increase verbosity in this case. I couldn't find any information on buildout's interaction with proxies neither at http://www.buildout.org/en/latest/docs/index.html (which is version 1.2.1!?) nor at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.2.1

```
pdobrogost@host:~/projects/projectx/projectx_buildout$ python bootstrap.py -c buildout-devel.cfg                 
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg
Getting distribution for 'setuptools'.
/opt/python/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'src_root'
  warnings.warn(msg)
Got setuptools 5.7.
Getting distribution for 'zc.buildout==1.4.3'.
Got zc.buildout 1.4.3.

pdobrogost@host:~/projects/projectx/projectx_buildout$ ./bin/buildout -vNc buildout-devel.cfg custom:cvsuser=pdobrogost
Installing 'mr.developer'.
We have no distributions for mr.developer that satisfies 'mr.developer'.
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/mr.developer/: hostname 'proxy.site.local' doesn't match either of '*.c.ssl.fastly.net', 'c.ssl.fastly.net', '*.target.com', '*.vhx.tv', '*.snappytv.com', '*.atlassian.net', 'secure.lessthan3.com', '*.atlassian.com', 'a.sellpoint.net', 'cdn.upthere.com', '*.tissuu.com', '*.issuu.com', '*.kekofan.com', '*.python.org', '*.theverge.com', '*.sbnation.com', '*.polygon.com', '*.twobrightlights.com', '*.2brightlights.info', '*.vox.com', 'staging-cdn.upthere.com', '*.zeebox.com', '*.beamly.com', '*.aticpan.org', 'stream.svc.7digital.net', 'stream-test.svc.7digital.net', '*.articulate.com', 's.t.st', 'vid.thestreet.com', '*.planet-labs.com', '*.url2png.com', 'turn.com', 'www.turn.com', 'rivergathering.org', 'social.icfglobal2014-europe.org', '*.innogamescdn.com', '*.pathable.com', '*.staging.pathable.com', '*.kickstarter.com', 'sparkingchange.org', 'www.swedavia.se', 'www.swedavia.com', 'js-agent.newrelic.com', '*.fastly-streams.com', 'cdn.brandisty.com', 'fastly.hightailcdn.com', '*.fl.yelpcdn.com', '*.feedmagnet.com', 'api.contentbody.com', '*.acquia.com', '*.swarmapp.com', '*.pypa.io', 'pypa.io', 'static.qbranch.se', '*.krxd.net', '*.room.co', '*.metrological.com', 'room.co', 'cdn.evbuc.com', 'cdn.adagility.com', '*.bandpage.com', '*.ibmserviceengage.com', '*.quirky.com', '*.veez.co', '*.x.io', '*.otoycdn.net', '*.scribd.com', 'www.dwin1.com', 'api.imgur-ysports.com', 'i.imgur-ysports.com', '*.fxcm.co.jp', 'listora.com', '*.listora.com', 'blendle.nl', '*.blendle.nl', '*.modeanalytics.com', 'modeanalytics.com', 'krux.com', '*.krux.com', '*.udemy.com', '*.1stdibs.com', 'api.keep.com', 'www.piriform.com', '*.ustream.tv', 'www.zimbio.com', 'm.zimbio.com', 'www.stylebistro.com', 'm.stylebistro.com', 'm.lonny.com', 'www.lonny.com', 'assets.trabiancdn.com', '*.socialchorus.com', '*.heritagestatic.com', '*.theoutbound.com', 'img.rakuten.com', 'images.rakuten.com', 'img1.r10.io', 'ast1.r10.io', 'scribd.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'mr.developer' (maybe misspelled?)
Download error on http://pypi.python.org/simple/: hostname 'proxy.site.local' doesn't match either of '*.c.ssl.fastly.net', 'c.ssl.fastly.net', '*.target.com', '*.vhx.tv', '*.snappytv.com', '*.atlassian.net', 'secure.lessthan3.com', '*.atlassian.com', 'a.sellpoint.net', 'cdn.upthere.com', '*.tissuu.com', '*.issuu.com', '*.kekofan.com', '*.python.org', '*.theverge.com', '*.sbnation.com', '*.polygon.com', '*.twobrightlights.com', '*.2brightlights.info', '*.vox.com', 'staging-cdn.upthere.com', '*.zeebox.com', '*.beamly.com', '*.aticpan.org', 'stream.svc.7digital.net', 'stream-test.svc.7digital.net', '*.articulate.com', 's.t.st', 'vid.thestreet.com', '*.planet-labs.com', '*.url2png.com', 'turn.com', 'www.turn.com', 'rivergathering.org', 'social.icfglobal2014-europe.org', '*.innogamescdn.com', '*.pathable.com', '*.staging.pathable.com', '*.kickstarter.com', 'sparkingchange.org', 'www.swedavia.se', 'www.swedavia.com', 'js-agent.newrelic.com', '*.fastly-streams.com', 'cdn.brandisty.com', 'fastly.hightailcdn.com', '*.fl.yelpcdn.com', '*.feedmagnet.com', 'api.contentbody.com', '*.acquia.com', '*.swarmapp.com', '*.pypa.io', 'pypa.io', 'static.qbranch.se', '*.krxd.net', '*.room.co', '*.metrological.com', 'room.co', 'cdn.evbuc.com', 'cdn.adagility.com', '*.bandpage.com', '*.ibmserviceengage.com', '*.quirky.com', '*.veez.co', '*.x.io', '*.otoycdn.net', '*.scribd.com', 'www.dwin1.com', 'api.imgur-ysports.com', 'i.imgur-ysports.com', '*.fxcm.co.jp', 'listora.com', '*.listora.com', 'blendle.nl', '*.blendle.nl', '*.modeanalytics.com', 'modeanalytics.com', 'krux.com', '*.krux.com', '*.udemy.com', '*.1stdibs.com', 'api.keep.com', 'www.piriform.com', '*.ustream.tv', 'www.zimbio.com', 'm.zimbio.com', 'www.stylebistro.com', 'm.stylebistro.com', 'm.lonny.com', 'www.lonny.com', 'assets.trabiancdn.com', '*.socialchorus.com', '*.heritagestatic.com', '*.theoutbound.com', 'img.rakuten.com', 'images.rakuten.com', 'img1.r10.io', 'ast1.r10.io', 'scribd.com' -- Some packages may not be found!
Getting distribution for 'mr.developer'.
While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.
  Getting distribution for 'mr.developer'.
Error: Couldn't find a distribution for 'mr.developer'.
```

I have proxies set as following:

```
pdobrogost@host:~/projects/projectx/projectx_buildout$ env | grep proxy
http_proxy=http://proxy.site.local:8080
https_proxy=http://proxy.site.local:8080
no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.1,.site.local,192.168.*
```

Also, `buildout-devel.cfg` extends `buildout.cfg` where the following versions are specified:

```
[versions]
zc.buildout = 1.4.3
zc.recipe.egg = 1.2.2
```

For comparision, with `wget` I get this:

```
pdobrogost@host:~/projects/projectx/projectx_buildout$ wget http://pypi.python.org/simple/mr.developer
--2014-09-05 10:56:20--  http://pypi.python.org/simple/mr.developer
Resolving proxy.site.local... 192.168.10.132
Connecting to proxy.site.local|192.168.10.132|:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://pypi.python.org/simple/mr.developer [following]
--2014-09-05 10:56:20--  https://pypi.python.org/simple/mr.developer
Connecting to proxy.site.local|192.168.10.132|:8080... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name “*.c.ssl.fastly.net” doesn’t match requested host name “pypi.python.org”.
To connect to pypi.python.org insecurely, use ‘--no-check-certificate’.
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is directly related, but your post came up when trying to find an answer to my problem.  It looks like there may be an issue with some versions of Python (3.4 in my case) where it could not install dependencies behind a proxy.  It looks like it's related to [this](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/385): (https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/385)  It looks like the buildout script may be running into the same issue?

For a work-around in my case where I'm only using pip, I was able to install each dependency manually.  So keep trying to install the main package with pip, then when it fails saying it can't find a package, pip install that package and try again.

Comment: This helped me. Manually running ``pip install`` on the failing package, then re-running the original ``pip install`` solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using http, by selecting different mirror that supports http as outlined in this guide -- http://jacobian.org/writing/when-pypi-goes-down/

For buildout, you will need to add the following as global declaration

```
[global]
index-url = http://pypi.python.org/simple
```

The main problem, however that pypi.python.org is now set up to serve https only and will still redirect you to https site even if your using http, so the only real solution is to create a mirror somewhere outside and serve pypi content via http.